# how to set common time sleep for exporting all data in different webpages in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

i Am doing UI automation in multiple webpages, handled all webpages in single script, My problem is in a webpage there is 100 data, to export that it will take 10 sec, in another webpage that contains 500 data  that will take 50 sec to export.

``

```
def Export():
global status,driver,wait
#driver.implicitly_wait(300)
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@name,'confirm')]").click()
    print("Export Button Clicked")
    time.sleep(50)
except:
    status="fail"
    print("Export Button Not Displayed")
```

Export():

I am expecting to set common time sleep for all webpages to export data

How to handle it?

Comment: set a timeout for the entire script and adjust it according to the maximum time it should take to export the data from the webpage
`timeout = 60 # seconds`
`time.sleep(timeout)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a timeout for the entire script and adjust it according to the maximum time it should take to export the data

```
import time

timeout = 60 # seconds

def export():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@name,'confirm')]").click()
        print("Export Button Clicked")
        
        time.sleep(timeout)
    except:
        status="fail"
        print("Export Button Not Displayed")
export()
```

or you can use an explicit wait function

```
def export():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@name,'confirm')]").click()
        print("Export Button Clicked")
        
        # Wait for export to finish before proceeding
        export_complete = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//export-complete"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(export_complete)
    except:
        status="fail"
        print("Export Button Not Displayed")

export()
```

**Update**

*Combination between timeout and the explicit wait*

```
timeout = 60 # seconds

def export():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@name,'confirm')]").click()
        print("Export Button Clicked")
        
        # Wait for export to finish or timeout
        export_complete = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//export-complete"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(export_complete)
    except:
        status="fail"
        print("Export Button Not Displayed")

export()
```

Comment: will try and update about above two methods

Comment: above two function working for me, but problem is if data has been exported in 10 sec in one webpage,  but driver wait for 60 sec then move to next step, i am expecting if data exported in 10 sec then immediately driver will go to next step

Comment: You can try using a combination of both approaches  Set an explicit wait for the export process to complete, and set a maximum timeout for the entire process ,the script will wait for the export process to complete, but if it takes longer than the maximum timeout, it will proceed to the next step.I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. You should never use hardcoded pauses.
   You need to get indication data is exported. It can be done according to some expected changes on web page or maybe file is downloaded and exists on the disk etc.
2. In case there is no way to avoid this and you can only use hardcoded pauses you can set some kind of dictionary of delay values per web site so you will be able to get the delay value (value) per link (key).